# Куб минимального объема

Tags: алгоритм, множества, вычислительная-геометрия

> На множестве точек n-мерного пространства определить координаты
>   вершин n-мерного гиперкуба содержащего внутри себя все точки исходного
>   множества, гиперкуб должен быть минимального объема.

Возникла вот такая задача, не могу придумать адекватный алгоритм. Может есть у кого-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66754/discussion-on-question-by-fil---).

Comment: Если подходящего ответа так и не будет — маякните, открою конкурс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет просто о каком-то работающем алгоритме (возможно неоптимальном), то я бы подошел к вопросу так:

1. Сначала составляется [функционал](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB), то есть некая функция с некими параметрами, которая выдает на гора 1 значение
2. Далее уже можно применить любой алгоритм минимизации функционала (а их туча)

То есть с точки зрения алгоритмирования, интерес представляет только составление самого функционала.

Шаги вычисления функционала я бы видел такие:

1. Задаемся кубом, вычисляем его объем - обозначим его как `V`
2. Берем каждую из точек и определяем находится точка внутри куба или нет
3. Если точка внутри куба определяем излишний объем `dv=0`
4. Если точка вне куба излишний объем `dv` определяем как `2*V` (как вариант - можно придумать что-то более интересное и непрерывное)
5. Суммируем все `dv` и прибавляем к `V`

В итоге получим `2n`-мерный функционал (координаты 1-го из ребер куба однозначно характеризуют его положение в пространстве), который просто надо минимизировать - то есть понять при каком положении куба полученный объем будет минимален.

Теперь дело за малым - засовываем полученный функционал в более-менее любой алгоритм минимизации функционала (по сути это вообще чуть ли не библиотечные функции в вычметодах), задаем некое начальное значение положения куба и вперед.

Comment: Неужели задача не имеет _точного_, неитеративного решения?

Comment: Да хз... Подумай над 2-мерным вариантом - набор точек на плоскости и найти квадрат минимальной площади полностью покрывающим эти точки.

Comment: Разве этот вопрос не про выпуклую оболочку? Т.е. в R^n строим выпуклую оболочку. А для неё находим куб.

Comment: @hedgehogues, а как для выпуклой оболочки найти минимальный куб?

Comment: По-моему это можно сделать за O(n^4), перебрав все точки и построив все квадраты. Среди них выбрав меньший по площади. http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/290/%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC

Comment: @Barmaley а вы уверены, что Ваш алгоритм сойдётся к минимальному кубу? У меня что-то сомнения возникли.

Comment: Вот, кстати, ещё https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2_n-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5

Comment: @VladD Задача имеет точное решение (как минимум одно, как максимум - континуум), так как тут минимизируется непрерывная функция (объём) на компакте (множество всех ортогональных базисов в $\mathbb R^n$). Как построить хотя бы одно такое решение - это совершенно другой вопрос. Может статься, что сумеем построить точный алгоритм с оценками на сложность, а может - что придётся использовать итеративный приближённый в духе численной оптимизации.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: Я знаю теорему Вейерштрасса, вопрос планировался как риторический.

Comment: @VladD Пусть случайно забредший сюда первокурсник  будет знать, что у задачи есть решение и на основе какой теоремы это можно доказать=)

Answer (score 1):

В случае n=2 для выпуклого многоугольника есть линейный алгоритм построения ограничивающего прямоугольника минимальной площади.

Есть обобщение на n=3 для множества точек, там алгоритм ведёт себя как третья степень.

Источник: [английская википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms)

Я не разбирался с построением этих алгоритмов, но есть подозрение, что точное решение для куба/квадрата будет

1. гораздо сложнее, чем для прямоугольника/прямоугольного параллелепипеда
2. при n>3 будет себя вести препротивнейшим образом

Comment: Из процитированной вами статьи: _It is based on the observation that a side of a minimum-area enclosing box must be collinear with a side of the convex polygon_. Это подходит для случая прямоугольника, но не очевидно (и скорее всего неверно) в случае куба.

Comment: @VladD полностью согласен.